# String comparison ==, when it ignores white spaces

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have the following method inside my asp.net mvc web application, to check if an ip address already exists or not:-

```
public bool ISTMSIPUnique(string ip, int? id=0) 
{
    var technology = FindTechnology(id.Value);
    var result = tms.TechnologyIPs.Where(a.IPAddress.ToUpper() == ip.ToUpper());
    return (result.Count() == 0);
}
```

But I have noted that the `a.IPAddress.ToUpper() == ip.ToUpper()` will do the following:-

1. It will assume that “test” and “test  ” are the same. (it will ignore white spaces at the end of the character).
2. But will assume that the “test” and “  test  ”, white space to the left and to the right are two different strings.

So what is the rule behind this? Should I always trim() the string before saving it to the SQL server DB to overcome this problem Since IP addresses can not contain whitespace?

Comment: Sounds like you should put some constraints in your database not to allow any whitespace.

Comment: .NET never ignores whitespace when comparing strings.

Comment: `It will assume that “test” and “test ” are the same.` This isn't true, something else is happening that you aren't seeing. You should also be using `string.Compare` specifying a `StringComparison` value that ignores case rather than using `ToUpper` on both stings here.

Comment: Is tms.TechnologyIPs a standard object, or is it some Entity Framework collection? The LINQ implementation will vary.

Comment: it is an entity framework collection..

Comment: I don't think == inside a Where() is going to be using the String == operator.

Comment: Could LINQ be building SQL that doesn't care about whitespace when run on the database?

Comment: @Ian Nelson. Excellent call on EF. This is effectively what you are doing: (In Sql Server Context)
    `BEGIN
      IF('test ' = 'test')
     SELECT 'true'
 ELSE
  SELECT 'false'
       END`
Preston has a better explanation why

Comment: @JimRhodes That depends entirely on *which* `Where` method is being invoked. In this case, since `tms.TechnologyIPs` is an instance of `ObjectSet<TEntity>`, the `Where` method will come from `Queryable`, where the provider is responsible for translating the expression into, in this case, SQL.

Answer (score 9):

Since you posted the detail that this is *actually* using EF, my comment regarding string comparisons isn't valid.

Assuming your database is Sql Server, or any database that conforms to ANSI standards for string comparisons, strings are padded to be the same length before comparison. So 'test' is padded to be the same length as 'test ', by appending a white space character, before the strings are compared, thus they evaluate as equal. Conversely when comparing 'test' and ' test', 'test' is padded to 'test ' to be the same length as ' test', which still results in the strings not comparing as equivalent.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316626

Comment: +1, very interesting!  This explains the problem.  I'm surprised I haven't caught this happening before in my code.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely "test" and "test " are different strings. Framework never ignores spaces.

I would save trimmed string into the database. Also I would suggest to use **string.Equals** for strings comparison.

BTW if you are working with ip addresses, why do you need to call ToUpper method?

I suggest to read this article. It is about string intern pool. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.intern.aspx. Very useful!

*The common language runtime conserves string storage by maintaining a table, called the intern pool, that contains a single reference to each unique literal string declared or created programmatically in your program. Consequently, an instance of a literal string with a particular value only exists once in the system.
For example, if you assign the same literal string to several variables, the runtime retrieves the same reference to the literal string from the intern pool and assigns it to each variable.*

Comment: Perhaps it's dealing with IPv6. Though I would have used `.Equals` with a `StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase`

Answer (score -1):

'test' and ' test' are different strings for sure

For your case, I reckon you need to clean the ip address when saving to the database so that you don't need to clean the ips ever time.

Also, I think it is a good practice to use String.Equals to compare to string as well (you have more control there e.g. whether ignoring the case...) and if you want to clear the white space or some other characters, clean that before passing to the function.

```
string cleaned1 = clean your input
string cleaned2 = clean your input

bool stringEquals = String.Equals(
    cleaned1, 
    cleaned2, 
    StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```